# How to create custom keyboard shortcut using native android soft keyboard

Tags: android, mobile, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method, soft-keyboard

I am Trying to create an application which will implement a shortcut in soft android keyboard for example if i have saved in my application (a pattern) that on double pressing the '@' symbol on the (native) keyboard it should place my email address on the edit text,could any body  help me out as i am  new to android development.
Thanks in advance